# How to force SharedPreferenceChangeListener notification when updating key with the same value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

`SharedPreferenceChangeListener` can (and does!) skip notifications when db is updated with the same value e.g. `boolean` value from `true` to `true`. In practice you get notified when value is changed to a different value.

How can I get notification on every SharedPreference key/value update?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, naive solution is to **remove** a key/value pair when it exists in SharedPreferences. Remember to **ignore empty notification** in `SharedPreferenceChangeListener`. You'll be notified when value is removed and when new value is inserted.

Check out `preferenceManager.remove(key)` in:

```
open class MyBasePreferences : KoinComponent {

    val context: Context by inject()
    val preferenceManager: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

    /**
     * Saves primitive value to shared preferences
     */
    fun SharedPreferences.save(key: String, value: Any?) {
        if (value == null)
            throw RuntimeException("Trying to save null value!")

        if (preferenceManager.contains(key))
            preferenceManager.remove(key)
        preferenceManager.edit {
            when (value) {
                is String -> putString(key, value)
                is Long -> putLong(key, value)
                is Boolean -> putBoolean(key, value)
                is Int -> putInt(key, value)
                is Float -> putFloat(key, value)
                else -> throw RuntimeException("Type not supported in Preferences!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

custom `SharedPrefChangeListener`:

```
class MySharedPrefChangeListener : SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, KoinComponent {

    /**
     * Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed.
     */
    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null)
            return

        if (sharedPreferences.contains(key)) {
            when (key) {
                "YOUR_KEY" -> {
                    // action to perform
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

inside App class:

```
/**
 * Main application class
 */
class MyApp : Application(), KoinComponent {

    var preferenceManager: SharedPreferences? = null
    var prefChangeListener: MySharedPrefChangeListener? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        prefChangeListener = MySharedPrefChangeListener()
        preferenceManager?.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefChangeListener)
    }
}
```